# How to calculate module $a\cdot7 \equiv1\pmod8$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How should i calculate following module ?

$a\cdot7 \equiv1\pmod8$

is value of $a = 1$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you decide whether it is true that $1*7\equiv1\pmod8$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every natural number $n$ we have $(-1)*(n-1)  \equiv (-1)^2 = 1 \bmod n$. So in your example $a \equiv -1 \equiv 7 \bmod 8$.

Comment: of course you mean $a = 8k+7$ for $k = 0 , 1 , ....$

Comment: I mean what I have written, and it is correct (and why not $k=-1$?).

Comment: sorry my mistake, I dont know why I saw $a \equiv -1 \equiv 7$ as $a = 7$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $ $ mod $\,8\!:\ 8\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}{7\equiv -1},\ $ so $\ \color{#c00}7a\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow (\color{#c00}{-1})a\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\,a\equiv\, \ldots$

Comment: To the downvoter: if you tell me what is not clear to you then I can explain it further.